# Submit form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, submit

I feel really silly for having to ask this *head desk* but I've got no idea why this code isn't working it really simple *sigh*

I'm getting the following JavaScript error when I select from either of the drop downs and the form doesn't submit.

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object # is not a function

```
<form action="categories/view/52" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="myform" name="myform"> 
<select name="sort" ID="sort_type" onchange='document.forms["myform"].submit();'>   
  <option value="label">Sort</option> 
  <option value="price-low-high">Price: Low - High</option> 
  <option value="price-high-low" selected="selected">Price: High - Low</option> 
  <option value="name-a-z">Name A - Z</option> 
  <option value="name-z-a">Name Z - A</option> 
  <option value="date-added-new">Date Added - New</option>  
  <option value="date-added-old">Date Added - Old</option> 
</select> 
<select name="limit" ID="sort_type" onchange='document.forms["myform"].submit();'>   
  <option value="items_3" selected="selected">3</option> 
  <option value="items_50">50</option> 
  <option value="items_100">100</option> 
  <option value="items_all">all</option> 
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  />
```

The submit function has been clobbered with that HTMLElementNode.

The simple solution is to rename it, or remove the name.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
```

If you can't rename it (because you have server side code that depends on that value being submitted and you can't change the server side code) then you can:

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.forms["myform"]);
```

Comment: Oh of cause I new it would be something simple I was over looking, it works now thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error when trying to call form.submit() is that your submit button is called "submit". This means that the "submit" property of your Form object is now a reference to the submit button, overriding the "submit" method of the form's prototype.

Renaming the submit button would allow you to call the submit() method without error.

```
<input type="submit" name="submitEle" value="submit"  />
```

Should work